# Minimising MAPE for a constant predictor

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, constants

I have a constant predictor $f(x_i) = C$, and a set of true labels $y_i \geq 1$

How to find explicit formula for the C which minimises Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE), that is:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n  \left|\frac{y_i-C}{y_i} \right|\rightarrow \min_{C}
$$

I tried taking sub-derivative, and found that I need to somehow equate to zero the following:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n  \frac{sign(y_i-C)}{y_i} =0
$$

but I have no idea where to go next. I know that I can use some optimisation or iterative methods, but I want to get an explicit equation for $C$.